# The buttons in project delete the squares?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I have problem with my C# winform project.

I have function that draw squares:

```
public void DrawingSquares(int x, int y)
{
  System.Drawing.Graphics graphicsObj;
  graphicsObj = this.CreateGraphics();
  Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 5);
  Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, 100, 100);
  graphicsObj.DrawRectangle(myPen, myRectangle);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  z = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text)-1;
  k = Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text)-1;
  DrawAllSquares();
}

private void DrawAllSquares()
{
  int tempy = y;
  for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
  {
    DrawingSquares(x, y);
    for (int j = 0; j < k - 1; j++)
    {
      tempy += 50;
      DrawingSquares(x, tempy);
    }
    x += 50;
    tempy = y;
  }
}
```

In my project, I have a function that I use to move button around the form at runtime, but when the button is moved onto the drawing the drawing is deleted.

What can I do to make the drawing permanent?

Comment: please clarify me when this method is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need permanently (in terms of application life time), by any means, you need to use it inside you `Control's` (the `Control` where rectangle is have to be drawn), [OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx) method.

If you need an `animation` too: it *could* be resolved by using a `timer` and changing coordinates that you pass like a parameters to your `DrawSquares`.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

A pseudocode:

```
public class MyControl : Control 
{
    public override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
       base.OnPaint(e); 

       DrawingSquares(e.Graphics, valueX, valueY);
    }

    public void DrawingSquares(Graphics graphicsObj, int x, int y)
    {      
       Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 5);
       Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, 100, 100);
       graphicsObj.DrawRectangle(myPen, myRectangle);
    }

}
```

`valueX` and `valueY` are relative `X` and `Y` coordinates where you want the rectangle to be drawn.

These coordinates can be constant values, or you can change them from some timer and call `Invalidate()` on `MyControl`, so paint will be executed.

Comment: +1 but note that in general you should really only redraw the rectangles that intersect with `e.ClipRectangle` - though in a simple case like this it's probably fine to redraw them all as long as you don't have too many.

Comment: @Rup: yes:) but you jump into advanced steps. OPs asking only about how to draw *in general*, after if he will meet a performance problems due the large quantity of drawing shapes, will look on this too: there is a Client rectanlge, there is a ViewMatrix, there are could be objects that cover this rectangle,so no need to draw it at all and all related stuff...